# How do I match URLs with regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

We want to check if a URL matches mail.google.com or mail.yahoo.com (also a subdomain of them is accepted) but not a URL which contains this string after a question mark. We also want the strings "mail.google.com" and "mail.yahoo.com" to come before the third slash of the URL, for example `https://mail.google.com/` is accepted, `https://www.facebook.com/mail.google.com/` is not accepted, and `https://www.facebook.com/?mail=https://mail.google.com/` is also not accepted. `https://mail.google.com.au/` is also not accepted. Is it possible to do it with regular expressions?

```
var possibleURLs = /^[^\?]*(mail\.google\.com|mail\.yahoo\.com)\//gi;
var url;
// assign a value to var url.
if (url.match(possibleURLs) !== null) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Currently this will match both `https://mail.google.com/` and `https://www.facebook.com/mail.google.com/` , but we don't want to match `https://www.facebook.com/mail.google.com/`.

**Edit**: I want to match any protocol (any string which doesn't contain `"?"` and `"/"`) followed by a slash `"/"` twice (the string and the slash can both be twice), then any string which doesn't contain `"?"` and `"/"` (if it's not empty, it must end with a dot `"."`), and then `(mail\.google\.com|mail\.yahoo\.com)\/`. Case insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found that it works with:

```
var possibleURLs = /^([^\/\?]*\/){2}([^\.\/\?]+\.)*(mail\.google\.com|mail\.yahoo\.com)\//gi;
```

Comment: You probably should add this to your question or format this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not being funny - but why must it be a regular expression?

Is there are reason why you couldn't simplify the process using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) (or webkitURL in Chrome and Safari) - the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.URL) simply takes a string and then contains properties for each part of the URL.  Whether it supports all the host types that you want to support, I don't know.

Granted, you might still need a regex after that (although really you'd just be checking that the hostname ends with either yahoo.com or google.com), but you would just be running it against the hostname of the URL object rather than the whole URI.

The API is not ubiquitous, but seems reasonably well supported and, anyway, if this is client-side validation then I hope you're checking it on the server, too, because sidestepping javascript validation is easy.

Comment: We match the URLs in an extension for Google Chrome, Firefox or Safari (done in the background). We receive the URL as a string and we want to do something if the URL matches a specific domain, such as mail.google.com. The easiest way to do it is with regular expressions, but if you have another suggestion please be more specific - how will the code to match URLs look like in Chrome, Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 1):

```
^([-a-z]+://|^cid:|^//)([^/\?]+\.)?mail\.(google|yahoo)\.com/
```

Should do the trick

The first `^` means "match beginning of line", the second negates the allowed characters, thus making a slash `/` not allowed.

Nb. You still have to escape the slashes, or use it as a string in `new RegExp(string)`:

```
new RegExp('^([-a-z]+://|^cid:|^//)([^/\?]+\.)?mail\.(google|yahoo)\.com/')
```

Comment: The protocol doesn't have to be `https`, it can also be `http` or (theoretically) any other protocol. Also notice the subdomain, `https://test.mail.yahoo.com/` should be accepted (or even a sub-subdomain).

Comment: I understand, and that's exactly what this is, the questionmark after the `s` makes it optional, the `[^/]*\.?` allows for optional subdomains

Comment: Ok, there was a small error, which allowed `.mail.yahoo.com` for example, but I've updated my answer

Comment: updated to allow any type of URL; using a scheme, without a scheme and also cid urls

Comment: This matches `-------:`, not sure it's a valid url.

Comment: Probably not, but that's not what the question is about. Matching a scheme which only has single dashes in between letters makes the regex substantially longer.

Comment: Took that part from a regex in the Rails framework though: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L111

Comment: It matches `-------:` not simply for the scheme part but for the whole url.

Comment: Hm weird, lets check that.

Comment: I forget the `//`, try with `-------://`

Comment: Added extra parentheses around the scheme part, that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
^[a-z]+:\/\/([^.\/]+\.)*mail\.(google|yahoo).com\/
```

[**Regex Example Link**](https://regex101.com/r/sO7cR1/2)

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `[a-z]+` Matches the protocol. If you want a specific set of protocols, then `(https?|ftp)` may do the work
- `([^.\/]+\.)*` matches the subdomin part

Comment: @Koen. no it doesnt, contain dashes but underscore. But i dont think that may cause much of trouble. Anyways i have edited my answer to take care of that. Hope its fine now